# gridOptions.api.getSelectedRowsAFTERSORTING()

Tags: ag-grid

When I use gridOptions.api.getSelectedRows() on sorted dataset, array is created based upon original (and not sorted) order of items. Is there please a way to get an array based upon actual order of items?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See https://github.com/ceolter/ag-grid/issues/1451 for solution:

```
array = [];
gridOptions.api.forEachNodeAfterFilterAndSort(function(node) {
    array.push(node.data);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

From the Grid API [Docs](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-api) there is a method called `forEachNodeAfterFilterAndSort` which will allow you to iterate over the filtered and sorted nodes. You can then add these nodes to an array as you iterate over them.

Comment: Thank you. But callbacks from forEachNodeAfterFilterAndSort() seems to be asynchronous. So they cannot all reach the same array. Can you confirm it? Only thing that works for me is to save data to hidden html element and collect them afterwards. Which is solution I do not like. Is there any hope I will be able to use getSelectedRowsAfterFilterAndSort() one day?

Comment: @jathri The callbacks from forEachNodeAfterFilterAndSort are not asynchronous. You may include asychnronous code within them but they themselves are not and the call itself returns a void (TS) not a promise.

Answer (score 0):

This function will return selected nodes in sorted order (*adapted from jathri's answer*):

```
function getSelectedRows (gridApi) {
    const selectedNodes = [];

    // Need to call this instead of getSelectedNodes to preserve sorted order
    gridApi.forEachNodeAfterFilterAndSort(function mapSortedNode ({ data, selected }) {
        if (selected) {
            selectedNodes.push(data);
        }
    });

    return selectedNodes;
}
```

Comment: I believe the second parameter may be incorrect. For me, I see the callback function mapSortedNode accepts the parameters (node, idx). See https://ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/grid-api/#reference-rowNodes-forEachNodeAfterFilterAndSort 
`this.gridApi?.forEachNodeAfterFilterAndSort( (rowNode, _idx) => {
  let selectedNodes = [];
  if ( rowNode.isSelected() ) {
    selectedNodes.push(rowNode.data);
  }
});`